# .HTACCESS Redirection Problem: index.php Before URL Slug

Tags: redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, .htaccess

I am trying to achieve a simple http to https redirect and www to non-www. The problem is that .htaccess puts "index.php" before the url slug, resulting in a server error. Here is what happens:

WRONG BEHAVIOUR:

```
http://example.com/url-slug -> https://example.com/index.php/url-slug
```

DESIRED BEHAVIOUR:

```
http://example.com/url-slug -> https://example.com/url-slug
```

Note: I want all queries to redirect to the index.php page in the main directory, unless the requested file exists on the server. I'd like to achieve this without changing the url in the browser, which causes the server to crash.

(Objective: **www -> non-www & http -> https**)

CURRENT .HTACCESS SETTINGS:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `http to https` 301 redirect should be at the top before other internal rewrite rules

```
RewriteEngine On
#http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.